# Loop to move dir into same dir

Tags: shell, ubuntu, directory

I have this estructure:

```
-father
 |-t1
   |-1.jpg
   |-...
 |-t2
   |-2.jpg
   |-...
```

I Need to move folders `father/t1/...`  to `father/t1/t1/...` and `father/t2/...` to `father/t2/t2/...`

In order to stay with this structure

```
-father
 |-t1
   |-t1
     |-1.jpg
     |-...
 |-t2
   |-t2
     |-2.jpg
     |-...
```

I need a command to do this in a loop because I've many folders I need to move them.

Thanks

Comment: http://www.tldp.org/LDP/GNU-Linux-Tools-Summary/html/x4055.htm

Answer (score 1):

`mv file1 file2 target`

`mv folder1 folder2 target`

Just pass args to it or even `mkdir` before `mv` in your loop.